# AS3 : Reading the DOM

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, dom

I'm trying to read a specific DIV on the page using just ActionScript from my SWF.
Unfortunately I don't have access to the JS on the page.  I only receive null when I try to run this AS code.

```
var childTest:String = ExternalInterface.call("function expansionCheck(){return document.getElementById('myDIV').hasChildNodes();}") as String;
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'childTest is '+childTest);
```

I have verified that the param's are set correctly to make this happen.

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any console.log errors when you run that?

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax of ExternalInterface.call() method.

```
function call(functionName:String, ... arguments):*

- functionName:String — The alphanumeric name of the function to call in the container.
```

But you are not passing the function name instead you have the function itself.

Also **function expansionCheck()** should be there in the html page, so that you can access it using **ExternalInterface.call()** method.

Further, 
**Returns   *** — The response received from the container. If the call failed– for example, if there is no such function in the container, the interface is not available, a recursion occurred (with a Netscape or Opera browser), or there is a security issue– null is returned and an error is thrown.

Check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) for further details on ExternalInterface.call()

Example:

HTML PAGE

```
<script>
function expansionCheck(){
    return document.getElementById('myDIV').hasChildNodes();
}
</script>
```

ActionScript:

```
var childTest:String = ExternalInterface.call("expansionCheck") as String;
ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'childTest is '+childTest);
```

Comment: Based on your answer, this shouldn't work, but it does.  Is there something prohibited in the DOM, that is allowed in doing a simple browser version check?

var myType:String = ExternalInterface.call("function testBrowser(){return navigator.userAgent}") as String;